# How can I add more cars to the Special Vehicle list?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I went to the Garage that isn't the one at the safe house. I noticed that there was a prompt to press D-pad Right to access Special vehicles. So a list of one car opened and I selected it. This spawned me outside in a Eleghy RH8. Now not matter what I do to the car, I can go back to the garage and spawn a new one (Nothing custom saved from the previous afaik). So this seemed like a good way to always have a car other than the standard your Character has.

What I want to know, I how do I increase that list? Is that where buying cars comes into it?

So if anyone has already increased that special vehicle list, Please let me know how you did it :).

Comment: Did you preorder the special or collectors edition?

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to get returning player content on PC without previously playing?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/223071/4797)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is for cars bought in the Rockstar Store. The first one you get for free by joining the Rockstar Social Club. Cars bought on a dealers website are only delivered once to your garage. For the marina it is a bit different: There is only one slot and you can choose (by pressing LEFT on the D-Dad) which vessel to spawn there. You can do this an infinite number of times. This also applies to the helipads and hangars. You can only spawn vessels bought on a dealers website before.

Comment: You are correct, sir. You get that car by joining Rockstar Social Club.

Answer (score 1):

Vehicles purchased from the game Internet for game cash only appear in the garage once, ie if you trash it you gotta buy another. The special vehicle list must be something else (I've only got the Elegy too).

Comment: Nice answer but if you have a question it would be better off to ask it as a question and not an answer. You would get better results that way

Answer (score 0):

Thats where the collector's edition unique vehicles are :) like the Hotknife and Carbon RS, but you can only get those with a DLC code if you bought the collector's edition game.. or maybe buy a code on eBay.

Answer (score -2):

I have not tried it for the garage itself yet, but I bought a slip at the marina and subsequently purchased boats from the "Internet" ingame. These appear in a list at the marina, which seems to be the same mechanic.

So I´d say, purchased vehicles are likely to appear in that list.