# How to get the Duke O' Death?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I was watching some videos on YouTube showing how to get the Duke O' Death in GTA 5, however what I have seen is sort of unclear.

Some people say you must be a returning player on GTA 5 to get it (what does this mean too BTW?), some people don't say that. Some people say you have to be Trevor, some people don't. Some say the time of day matters, some don't. And apparently you can buy it from Warstock website (I can't).

Can someone please tell me how to get it?! GTA 5 came with my PS4 (I didn't play it on PS3) if that helps.

Comment: returning means you must have had it on ps3/xb360. I would answer it all but its 8am and I'm overnight. enghish dead.

Comment: Related: [Is there any way to get returning player content on PC without previously playing?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/223071/4797)

Answer (score 2):

As of July 26, 2021, all owners of the Enhanced versions of *GTA V* will now get the returning player content, including the [Duke O'Death](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Duke_O%27Death), regardless of if they're actually returning players. See [Returning Player Bonuses Available To All Players](https://www.reddit.com/r/gtaonline/comments/os1xzn/returning_player_bonuses_available_to_all_players/) for more info. I can confirm that I got the Duke O'Death and the other returning player content on the PC Steam version despite not having owned the PS3 nor Xbox 360 versions.

###### "Duel" random event

To acquire the Duke O'Death, you need to complete the "Duel" random event. With any character, go to [Route 68](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Route_68), [Grand Senora Desert](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Senora_Desert).

A Duke O'Death will be parked near a gas station west of the ownable [Los Santos Customs](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Los_Santos_Customs).

[image][image]

Take the car and a gang of [rednecks](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Rednecks_(GTA_V)) will immediately attack the protagonist. They will be driving two [Phantoms](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Phantom) and three [Dubstas](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Dubsta). Kill all of them or escape to complete the random event.

Once completed, two Duke O'Deaths will spawn in the map:

1. [El Burro Heights](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/El_Burro_Heights)
   [image]
2. [Grand Senora Desert](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Grand_Senora_Desert)
   [image]

- *Note 1:* This random event can only be done after the mission [Pulling Favors](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Pulling_Favors).
- *Note 2:* If The player decides not to take the car the first or the second time the event appears, the event will very rarely spawn back. To fix this, replay [Pulling Favors](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Pulling_Favors), then hopefully the event should spawn in, if not then replay it again or replay [Mr. Philips](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Philips).

<sup>Source: [*Random Events in *Grand Theft Auto V**. GTA Wiki](https://gta.fandom.com/wiki/Random_Events_in_GTA_V#Duel)</sup>
<sup>Images are from: [*Duel*. gtaguide.net](https://gtaguide.net/gta5/walkthrough/random-events/duel/)</sup>

---

The [Native Trainer included with Script Hook V](https://www.gta5-mods.com/tools/script-hook-v) also allows you to spawn the vehicles exclusive to the 'returning player' content, including the Duke O'Death.

Once it is installed, press <kbd>F4</kbd> in-game to show its menu. To make it spawn a vehicle, go to 'Vehicle' → 'Car Spawner' and then select the Duke O'Death.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question recently. It is one of a few returning player exclusives. That means you have started playing on the previous generation (Xbox 360, PS3) and moved over to the current generation (Xbox one, PS4). There is no other way to unlock the Duke o Death. Guides that tell you how to unlock it, but don't mention "returning player reward" quite likely assume you have got the content already, and therefore must already be a returning player.

What I can not confirm is whether you can bring the content in if you **start the game on a new console and then play it on an older console**.

Comment: Oh I get it now! Thanks. That sorta sucks but oh well. Hopefully there is some way around it but it seems unlikely. Thanks again.

Comment: @user117852 lend a ps3 and a legal copy of gtav. play prologue and upload 1 photo from phone after you get in franklins house, then restart ps4. it must work. if you were on pc it was [waaaaaaay easier](https://www.gta5-mods.com/misc/exclusive-content-for-returning-gtav-unlocker)

Comment: @user117852 also, don't forget to log into same psn account!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was buy the the game for Xbox 360 then bought another one for the Xbox one so I can get it now.

Answer (score -1):

How you get the dukes of death is go to los santos airport then go to the farthest corner. Next you must swim to the submarines then blow them up and kill youreself. then drive to sandy shores and one will be on the side of the road.